# Revoking Google oAUTH token will invalidate all other tokens based on the same client_id

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

When I independently generate several access tokens and then call `revokeToken` for one of them, any other created ones get invalid.

1. I have `client_id` and `client_secret` that I will use several times.
2. I create an instance of `google.auth.OAuth2` using these `client_id` and `client_secret`.
3. I perform OAuth dialog and get the code.
4. I get the token for this code.
5. I get Google Calendar API using the token and request calendars list. Successful!
6. I repeat steps 2...4 to obtain new`google.auth.OAuth2` instance and new token for it.
7. I get Google Calendar API using new token and request calendars list. Successful!
8. I repeat steps 2...4 to obtain second `google.auth.OAuth2` instance and new token for it.
9. I call `auth.revokeToken` for the first token
10. I get Google Calendar API using new token and request calendars list. Caught an exception: 'Invalid Credentials'.

Here is the code:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const readline = require('node:readline/promises');
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });

const client_id = '...';
const client_secret = '...';
const redirect_uri = '...';

async function getTokens(auth) {
    const authUrl = auth.generateAuthUrl({ access_type : 'offline', scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.calendarlist.readonly'] });
    const code = await rl.question(`Open ${authUrl} and enter code here: `);
    console.log(`CODE: [${code}]`)
    const result = await auth.getToken(code);
    return result.tokens;
}

async function getCalendars(auth) {
    const api = google.calendar({ version : 'v3', auth });
    const calendars = await api.calendarList.list({});
    console.log(`Total calendars : ${calendars.data.items.length}`);
}

async function getAuth() {  
    const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri);
    const tokens = await getTokens(auth);
    auth.setCredentials(tokens);        
    google.options({ auth });
    return auth;
}

(async () => {
        const auth1 = await getAuth();
        await getCalendars(auth1); // success
        
        const auth2 = await getAuth();
        await getCalendars(auth2); // success

        const auth3 = await getAuth();
        await auth1.revokeToken(auth1.credentials.access_token);
        await getCalendars(auth3); // fail
})();
```

According to information from the similar SO topics, this is known behaviour and it's expected that revoking tokens for specific `google.auth.OAuth2` instance will invalidate any credentials ever created using the same `client_id` and `client_secret` for the particular user.

My question: is there any workaround way to invalidate only specific token and let other ones work? I would like to make sure that specific token can't be re-used anymore, but any other tokens still work.